# display a div at different interval using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 different div, i want the div1 to fade in after 20s and fade-out after 10s and after 30s i want div2 to fade in and after 10s div2 should also fade out. this should keep happening on load of page

```js
  bubbleMessage1 = document.getElementById("bubbleMessage1");
  bubbleMessage2 = document.getElementById("bubbleMessage2");  
  
  bubbleMessage1.style.display = "none";
  bubbleMessage2.style.display = "none";
  
  
  $(function () {
    // Different timeouts for each divs
    setTimeout(function(){
      var times = [20000, 50000];
      var counter = 0;
      divs = $('#bubbleMessage1, #bubbleMessage2');
      function showDiv() {
      // hide all divs, filter current index, and fadeIn
      divs.hide().eq(counter).fadeIn(500, "linear"); 
      // set time out duration from array of times 
      setTimeout(showDiv, times[counter]);
      // cycle the counter     
      counter = (counter + 1) % divs.length;
      }; 
      showDiv();

    }, 20000)
 // show first div    
    });
```

```css
.chat-bubble-1{
  width: 230px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #486622;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 22px;
  position: relative;
}
.chat-bubble-1::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #486622;
  border-right: 2px solid #486622;
  border-left: 0px solid #486622;
  border-top: 0px solid #486622;
  top : 100%;
  left: 74%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -22px;
  background: #486622;
}





@keyframes fadeOut {
0% {
  opacity: 1;
}
100% {
  opacity: 0;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


.fade-in{
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;

}

.fade-out{
    animation: fadeOut ease-in 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-container">
      <div class="chat-bubble-1" id="bubbleMessage1">
        Hi i'm bot How can i help you?
      </div>
      <div class="chat-bubble-1" id="bubbleMessage2">
        I'm still here How can i help you?
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to use setTimeout loop to achieve this but i was getting error.then i found this jquery method.the problem is the div will not fade-out after 10s. div1 fades and div2 comes immediately. Can anyone please give a solution really appreciate it.thanks

Comment: If you want a delay between fadeout and fadein, can you do something like `divs.hide().delay(4000).eq(counter).fadeIn(500, "linear");`

Answer (score 0):

> The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and
> successor to Window.setTimeout()) sets a timer which executes a
> function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

setTimeout gets extra args you can use in your code.

Change for instance from:

```
setTimeout(showDiv);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(showDiv, times[counter], times, (i+1)%2);
```

instead of using local vars.

Working demo:

```js
bubbleMessage1 = document.getElementById("bubbleMessage1");
bubbleMessage2 = document.getElementById("bubbleMessage2");

bubbleMessage1.style.display = "none";
bubbleMessage2.style.display = "none";

// Different timeouts for each divs
setTimeout(function(t, i){
    var times = t;
    var counter = i;
    divs = $('#bubbleMessage1, #bubbleMessage2');
    function showDiv(t, i) {
        var times = t;
        var counter = i;
        // hide all divs, filter current index, and fadeIn
        divs.hide().eq(counter).fadeIn(500, "linear");
        // set time out duration from array of times
        setTimeout(showDiv, times[counter], times, (i+1)%2);
        //                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //  params added...
        // cycle the counter
        counter = (counter + 1) % divs.length;
    };
    showDiv(times, counter);

}, 2000, [2000, 5000], 0);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  params added...
```

```css
.chat-bubble-1{
    width: 230px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #486622;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    line-height: 66px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 22px;
    position: relative;
}
.chat-bubble-1::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #486622;
    border-right: 2px solid #486622;
    border-left: 0px solid #486622;
    border-top: 0px solid #486622;
    top : 100%;
    left: 74%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-top: -22px;
    background: #486622;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.fade-in{
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;

}
.fade-out{
    animation: fadeOut ease-in 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="chat-container">
    <div class="chat-bubble-1" id="bubbleMessage1">
        Hi i'm bot How can i help you?
    </div>
    <div class="chat-bubble-1" id="bubbleMessage2">
        I'm still here How can i help you?
    </div>
</div>
```